What does the empty set mean in $\pi_1(A\cap B) \cong \mathbb{Z} = \langle\gamma \mid \emptyset\rangle$? Why is it written?
In the article "The Fundamental Group of the Real Projective Plane" (on math3ma.com), it is stated that
$$\pi_1(A\cap B) \cong \mathbb{Z} = \langle\gamma \mid \emptyset\rangle$$
What does empty set mean? Why is it written?
My thinking : $\pi_1(A\cap B)$ is the  set of  all homotopy classes $[\gamma]$ of loop $\gamma$ in $A\cap B$

$\mathbb{Z}$ is the group generated by a single element and no relations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group

My thinking: ($\dots$). Isn't this just the definition of $\pi_1$?

@SineoftheTime  yes

The notation $\langle S\ |\ R \rangle$ denotes a group presentation with generators $S$ and relations $R$. See for example the article Presentation of a group on wikipedia.
In your case, $\langle \gamma\ |\ \emptyset \rangle$ denotes a group with one generator $\gamma$, and no relations. In other words, this is the free group with one generator, which is the infinite cyclic group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

I'll add here that working with presentations is useful when it comes to computing fundamental groups, because van Kampen's theorem is easily formulated in terms of presentations.
